# Slack uploading a document

Tags: slack, slack-api, zapier, slack-commands, slack-block-kit

I would like to know if there are any possible methods to make "upload a document" feature in Slack Workflow. Or maybe some great connection with Zapier will also work. I found some API features but it isn't exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to Workflow Builder, there aren't any Slack-native Workflow steps that would allow users to upload files using your Workflow Builder app. But if you have Zapier installed on your Workspace you can check whether they offer a Workflow Step that involves file uploads.
https://my.slack.com/apps/collection/workflows

If you're referring to general Slack API apps, then you may want to use the `files.upload` method. But this method will only let your app upload specific files. If you want your end users to *choose* a file and upload it, then I'm afraid this method will not achieve that.